# alfresco search results : -> add parameter to search item url

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, aikau

I wanted to change the url of search result,
I found that this is an aikau page ,
The **faceted-search** page returns multiple results ,
If we click on search result item which is document then it's redirects us to document-details page ,
[image]
as shown in image the url `/share/page/site/swsdp/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/5fa74ad3-9b5b-461b-9df5-de407f1f4fe7` i wanted to add one parameter here

like this  `/share/page/site/swsdp/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/5fa74ad3-9b5b-461b-9df5-de407f1f4fe7&searchTerm=web` is there any way to add this parameter,
please help.
**searchTerm=web**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overrided aikau widget **FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT** with my custom widget files by

```
var searchResultWidget = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel.widgets, "id", "FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT");

if(searchResultWidget) {
    searchResultWidget.name = "custom/alfresco/search/AlfSearchResult";
}
```

So my widget **FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT**  will be like this

```
{
                     id: "FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT",
                     name: "custom/alfresco/search/AlfSearchResult",
                     config: {
                        enableContextMenu: false
                     }
                  }
```

and able to call my custom widget js file and changed the url.